# What is the difference between "Persan" and "Persique" in French?

Tags: adjectifs, noms-propres, toponymes

There are two translations for "Persian" in French: "Persan" and "Persique". For example, "Tapis Persan" for "Persian Rug" but "Golfe Persique" for "Persian Gulf". What's the difference? Are they exchangeable? What are some examples of "Persique"?

Answer (score 4):

There are more than two translations for Persian:

- Persique
- Persan
- Perse
- Farsi

and the forgotten

- Persien

*[Persique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persique)* is related to the ancient Persia (before the arabic invasion in the seventh century). *[Perse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perse/1)* is preferred nowadays and *persique* is rarely used outside of *Golfe persique*. Examples are *guerre persique*, war between the Greeks and Persians (Battle of Marathon, Darius, Xerxes...) and *feu persique* and old name for the *erysipelas* desease.

*[Persan](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persan)* is related to the "modern" Persia, i.e. after the seventh century, so is not exchangeable with persique.

*Persien* used to be a synonymous of *persan* and gave *[persienne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persienne)*.

Since 1935, *iranien* is preferred to *persan*.

*[Farsi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/farsi)* is mostly used to name the language (also *persan*) and the specificity of the Arabic alphabet used in Persia.

Comment: There are more than two translations....quand même. tapis perses, Lettres Persanes, deux exemple assez connus....used to be a synomym, luv.

Comment: @Lambie, "there **are**" indeed, thanks ! *Tapis perse* is almost never used in French, that's *tapis persan*. On the other hand, there is *étoffe perse* or *toile perse*.